# Watch didReceiveRemoteNotification on AppDelegate with Cordova Plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, appdelegate

We are working on a little plugin for cordova to watch the didReceiveRemoteNotification event.

This event is called on the AppDelegate.

So this is a problem because we are creating the plugin and want to keep it as a plugin, thus not altering the default AppDelegate.

Is there a way to set my plugin as a delegate for the notification so we can reuse our plugin?